# Working example of MvxRestClient.MakeRequestAsync with MvxJsonRequest

Tags: c#, json, networking, mvvmcross

I have just started working with `Mvvmcross` in a Core library for a multiplatform project.

I want to use the `Mvvmcross.Network` plugin with the `Mvvmcross.Json` plugin, but I am unable to find a good example combining this two plugins. I have watched all the N+1 videos and I guess this wasn't implemented at the time the videos where uploaded.

Ideally, I would like to know how to make an async request, with a json request and a json response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you missing from this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a regression bug in the all versions of Mvvmcross(Mvx) 4.1.4 and up to the current latest stable of 4.2.2. Where the callback approach described in the [readme](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Network) is missing from the interfaces `IMvxJsonRestClient` and `IMvxRestClient`. The issue has been resolved in the current [master branch](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Network) (Commit: [a5561b](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/commit/a55641b48198d10a6cd487f66c678467db2b13ff) and [fb2feb7](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/commit/fb2feb7224f5fe5007962f5b181f0dbf61fce943)), so it's highly likely it will be fixed in the next release.

---

If you want to use `MvvmCross.Plugins.Json` to deserialize your JSON responses, then rather user `MvxJsonRestClient` over the standard `MvxRestClient`.

Here is an example of the `MvxJsonRestClient` using [JSONPlaceholder](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#creating-a-resource) API:

**Approach - Callback**

You can use the callback approach when using Mvx version older than 4.1.4 and most likely in the versions after 4.2.2.

```
public void PostSample()
{
    var request = new MvxJsonRestRequest<UserRequest>
        ("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    {
        Body = new UserRequest
        {
            Title = "foo",
            Body = "bar",
            UserId = 1
        }
    };

    var client = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonRestClient>();
    client.MakeRequestFor(request,
        (MvxDecodedRestResponse<UserResponse> response) =>
        {
            // do something with the response.StatusCode and response.Result
        },
        error =>
        {
            // do something with the error
        });
}
```

**Approach - Async**

You can use the Async approach when using Mvx version 4.1.4 and up.

```
public async Task PostSampleAsync()
{
    var request = new MvxJsonRestRequest<UserRequest>
        ("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    {
        Body = new UserRequest
        {
            Title = "foo",
            Body = "bar",
            UserId = 1
        }
    };

    var client = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonRestClient>();
    var response = await client.MakeRequestForAsync<UserResponse>(request);

    // Check response.StatusCode if matches your expected status code
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        // interrogate the response object
        UserResponse user = response.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        // do something in the case of error/time-out/unexpected response code
    }
}
```

Request and Response classes

```
public class UserRequest
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
 }
```